# how do you check if the value is null and replace it by NA in R

Tags: r

I need to write a web service call that returns data as json:

```
{"application":"WEB","host":"prodwebserver01","dataCenter":"nevada","pod":"1"}
```

sometimes the data can be like this:

```
{"application":"null","host":"prodwebserver01","dataCenter":"nevada","pod":"1"}
or
{"application":"WEB","host":"prodwebserver01","dataCenter":"nevada","pod":"null"}
```

Sometimes, values like application:"null"

or dataCenter:"null" and when I do this:

```
zlinux<-data.frame(cbind(tolower(d$guestId),tolower(d$host),d$application,d$pod,tolower(d$dataCenter)))
```

keys that have null values does not show up on my zlinux data frame. If the value is null, I would like replace it by N_A and have 4 columns in my data frame.

The following is my code:

```
suppressMessages(library(RCurl))
suppressMessages(library(rvest))

guests<-c("web01", "web02", "web03")

url<-c("https://example.com/inventory/guest/")

zlinuxCMDB<-data.frame(guest=character(),host=character(),app=character(),pod=character(),dc=character())
for (i in guests) {
   url<-paste0(url,i)

   tryCatch({
            q<-getURL(url,ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
                tryCatch({
                        d<-fromJSON(q)
                        zlinux<-data.frame(cbind(tolower(d$guestId),tolower(d$host),d$application,d$pod,tolower(d$dataCenter)))
```

When any of the keys are null, I dont see them in my zlinux data frame. If the values are null, how would I replace them by NA and keep it my zlinux data frame?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "keys." Can you show us some of the data so we know what it looks like?

Comment: `d$guestId = ifelse(is.null(d$guestId), NA, d$guestId)` . Is that what you're looking for? How to replace null values in a vector with NA? Then just do this with all columns that you want to.

Comment: Which package is `fromJSON` coming from? `rjson` and `RJSONIO` both have this function.

Comment: This works for me. `d <- fromJSON('copy paste one of your example strings')` shows `d$application` is `"null"` (the string, not actually `NULL`)., and `zlinux` reflects this (by the way, you can do `data.frame(guestID=tolower(d$guestID), host=tolower(d$host)...)` without the `cbind`.  The reason you have no `d$guestID` is that your JSON doesn't.